# Proof of the Ultrametric Quality of $p$-adics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

We define the $p$-adic ordinal (or valuation) of $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ to be,
$$ \operatorname{ord}_p (x) := \max \{ r: p^r \mid x \} $$
and the $p$-adic norm of $x$ to be,
$$ |x|_p := 
\begin{cases} 
p^{-\operatorname{ord}_p (x)} & \text{if } x \ne 0 \\
p^{-\infty} = 0 & \text{if } x = 0
\end{cases} $$
I'm reading through a proof showing that this norm satisfies the ultra-metric inequality,
$$|x+y|_p \le \max \{ |x|_p, |y|_p \}$$
(where we have an equality only when $|x|_p \ne |y|_p$), but I'm not understanding the final step. I *do* understand that
$$ |x+y|_p = p^{-\operatorname{ord}_p (x+y)} \le p^{-\min \{ \operatorname{ord}_p (x), \: \operatorname{ord}_p (y) \}},
$$
but the author says that this implies that $|x+y|_p \le \max \{ |x|_p, |y|_p \}$. Unfortunately, I don't see why that is. I tried assuming (WLOG) that $\operatorname{ord}_p(x)$ was the minimum and simplifying the expression, but it didn't get anywhere. Could someone clarify?

Comment: $p^{-k}$ is maximum, when $k$ is minimum. $|x|_p$ and $|y|_p$ are each of the form $p^{-k}$. The largest is that which has smallest $k$. Now, $|x|_p=p^{-\operatorname{ord}_p(x)}$ and $|y|_p=p^{-\operatorname{ord}_p(y)}$. So, $\max(|x|_p,|y|_p)=p^{-\min(\operatorname{ord}_p(x),\operatorname{ord}_p(y))}$.

Comment: Thanks so much, that totally clarifies it; I feel so silly now!